# Getting minBound of a bounded type

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to do something like:

```
f :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => A a b -> [(a,b)]  
f x = [(as,bs) | as <- [minBound :: a ..] , bs <- x somefunction as]
```

but the minbound  there doesnt seem to work. how can I get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and use explicit `forall`s:

```
{-# ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a b . (Enum a, Bounded a) => A a b -> [(a,b)]  
f x = [(as,bs) | as <- [minBound :: a ..] , bs <- x somefunction as]
```

Without this, in Haskell every type signature is interpreted independently from the others. That is the `a` in `minBound :: a` has nothing to do with the `a` in the signature above.

If you really want to stick with no extensions, you can write an auxiliary function instead:

```
myBound :: Bounded a => A a b -> a
myBound x = minBound   -- does not really depend on x

f :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => A a b -> [(a,b)]  
f x = [(as,bs) | as <- [myBound x ..] , bs <- x somefunction as]
```

---

In this specific case, as @dfeuer points out below, there is a much simpler solution. We can simply remove the type annotation on `minBound`:

```
-- no extensions
f :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => A a b -> [(a,b)]  
f x = [(as,bs) | as <- [minBound ..] , bs <- x somefunction as]
```

This works because the list comprehension outputs pairs `(as,bs)`, so Haskell can see that `as` must have type `a`, and that `minBound` must be of the same type of `as`.

Comment: In this case, couldn't you avoid extensions by dropping the type signature? It'll be rather hard to understand, of course.

Comment: I personally think the `ScopedTypeVariables` approach is the best.